# I have a kernel density map in R, but I would like values of 0 to be transparent. How do I change the colors so this is possible?

Tags: r, plot, colors, spatial, kernel-density

I have a point pattern (ppp) which I have done a kernel density estimation on.
I have already changed the colour output using this:

`require(RColorBrewer)
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "black"))`

Then created the kernel density map (smktppp and W were previously specified):

`plot(density.ppp(smktppp, 0.5, edge=T), col=colfunc, main="Supermarket Density", window=W)`

[Here is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8itcn.jpg)

I would like to make the white parts (where the KDE/scale is at 0) transparent (with no fill). How would I go about doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Most plotting routines will leave NA values blank or "transparent". There's also sometime recognition of a value: "transparent". After looking at your plot I'm trying to figure out (without success) what difference you would expect when you made these changes?

Comment: The 0 values are not NA values though. It'd like to do this with three plots and then overlay them to create a map showing combined density. I can't do this at the moment as the white values on the next plot replace colored values in the first.

Comment: So have you tried the now blindingly obvious: `colorRampPalette(c("transparent", "black"))(5)`? (Do read the help page for  whatever plot function handles the `ppp`-class to see if it supports transparency, although that is usually a metter for the device to decide.)

Comment: This seems related to your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/42459424/3341769 which I tried to answer. Does this solve this problem also? If not I have given a short answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace pixel values by `NA` these will not be plotted and hence work as transparent. E.g.

```
smktim  <- density.ppp(smktppp, 0.5, edge=T)
smktim[smktim<1e-7] <- NA
```